# Discount text between 4 periods in year dates PHP

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in PHP and after alot of searching im asking it here.

I want to make a text that echo's the discount of that period. There are 4 periods jan - mar, apr - jun, jul - sep, okt - dec (every quarter).

But even when im in juli right now, it keeps showing discount quarter 4. 
I think it only looks at de value of the day and not to the month.

Another question is, how do i change the current time to a static date, so i can test with different dates.

```
I made the following code:

$current_time = date('d-m-Y');
$quarter1 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('01-01-2019'));
$quarter2 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('01-04-2019'));
$quarter3 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('01-07-2019'));
$quarter4 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('01-10-2019'));

if (($current_time > $quarter1 && $current_time < $quarter2 && $current_time < $quarter3 && $current_time < $quarter4)){
    // quarter 1
    echo "discount quarter 1";
}
elseif (($current_time > $quarter2 && $current_time < $quarter3 && $current_time < $quarter4)){
    // quarter 2
    echo "discount quarter 2";
}
elseif ($current_time > $quarter3 && $current_time < $quarter4){
    // quarter 3
    echo "discount quarter 3";
}
else {
    // quarter 4
    echo "discount quarter 4";
}
```

Comment: You compare __strings__ not dates.

Comment: Use Y-m-d format for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out you are comparing the strings in d-m-Y format, which will produce unexpected results.  Instead you would be better of comparing just the timestamp itself.

This code also simplifies the `if... elseif...` structure as you can assume if it's > quarter 2 (for example) then you don't need to then check if the date is less than.  I have also changed this to `<=` so that the quarters themselves are checked (this you will have to decide if you want the date to be inclusive or not)...

```
$current_time = strtotime("now");
$quarter1 = strtotime('01-01-2019');
$quarter2 = strtotime('01-04-2019');
$quarter3 = strtotime('01-07-2019');
$quarter4 = strtotime('01-10-2019');

if ( $current_time >= $quarter1 )    {
    if ( $current_time <= $quarter2 ){
        // quarter 1
        echo "discount quarter 1";
    }
    elseif ( $current_time <= $quarter3 ){
        // quarter 2
        echo "discount quarter 2";
    }
    elseif ( $current_time <= $quarter4){
        // quarter 3
        echo "discount quarter 3";
    }
    else {
        // quarter 4
        echo "discount quarter 4";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This works like a charm and looks very logic to me now. I tried it with different dates and changed the current time string to strtotime('30-06-2019'); for example to test with different dates. 

Thanks aigan!

Answer (score 1):

More simple with comparing directly timestamp
You don't need a very complicated logic

```
    $current_time = (new DateTime('now'))->getTimestamp();

    if ($current_time < strtotime('01-04-2019')) {
        echo "discount quarter 1";
    } else if ($current_time < strtotime('01-07-2019')) {
        echo "discount quarter 2";
    } else if ($current_time < strtotime('01-10-2019')){
        echo "discount quarter 3";
    } else {
        echo "discount quarter 4";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how i make it universal for every year? Because this is now for 2019 right?

Comment: You can concatenate current year like strtotime('01-04-'. date('Y')) [quarter 1] and so on  for every condition